# Target custom field type plugin value using WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, using the CTU plugin, I made a custom post type called apartments with a field called available. I only want to target any post with available=yes. How would I do this? I tried the_post('available=yes')

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'apartment'  
        );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


?>
<?php if( have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
        <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $the_field('available'); ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is this `$the_field` which you are using . ?

Comment: It's a field for the CTU plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the simplest solution is:
1. In your custom taxonomy create a term called available
2. add this to your custom query

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'apartment',
        'category_name' => 'available'  
    );
```